# Ionic - item não faz bind no nav-bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um ícone no nav-bar que deve exibir ou não conforme posição true/false do toggle. Testando na view funciona perfeitamente mas o resultado não funciona na nav bar. Ambas as páginas usam o mesmo controller.

**index.html - nav-bar**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <i class="icon ion-eye" ng-show="vaovivo.valor"></i>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-bar>
```

**Account.html - toggle**

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="vaovivo.valor" ng-checked="vaovivo.valor">
  Modo ao Vivo
</ion-toggle>
```

**Controllers.js**

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {    
  $scope.vaovivo = {'valor':false}
})
```

Comment: Acho que o que vc precisa é algo como isto: (Não tive tempo de estudar então não tenho certeza) http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2595-using-scope-digest-as-a-performance-optimization-in-angularjs.htm